# Exception "function does not exist" when executing PostgreSQL stored function via JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, stored-functions

I have problems calling a PostgreSQL function from JDBC with circumstances as follows. Stored function `endpoint_organizations` is defined like this:

```
postgres=# \df public.endpoint_organizations   
                                             List of functions
 Schema |          Name          |             Result data type             | Argument data types |  Type  
--------+------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------
 public | endpoint_organizations | TABLE(organizationid integer, name text) | staffid1 integer    | normal
(1 row)
```

I am calling it from Java like this:

```
int staffId = 1
PreparedStatement endpointOrganizations = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM endpoint_organizations (?)");
endpointOrganizations.setInt(1, staffId);
ResultSet resultSet = endpointOrganizations.executeQuery();
```

And I receive this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: function endpoint_organizations(integer) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 15
```

What could be the reason why? If I am not mistaken, this has worked before. I've double-checked and triple-checked now, but don't see what might cause the problem.

Comment: Do you have permission to execute on that function with the jdbc user? If not grant execute on function endpoint_organizations;

Comment: @d1ll1nger Yes, I have. If I `psql -U <user>` into the database and `select * from endpoint_organizations(1)` there, things work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was (of course) a stupid mistake on my part. I had made recent updates also to the stored function after connecting to PostgreSQL with `psql -U <user>` instead of `psql -U <user> <database>`, i.e. updates affected database `postgres` instead of `<database>`, whereas JDBC connected to `<database>`.

After performing updates on the right database, things are now back to normal.